# Unable to change compiler in Crypto++ GNUmakefile

Tags: compilation, crypto++

I'm trying to compile cryptopp with gcc49 on FreeBSD 10.x, however no matter how I instruct the Makefile to compile with g++49/gcc49, my attempts are ignored and it always compiles with c++.

I can't see at the moment where the compiler is defined in Makefile.

What I tried:

```
ifeq ($(CXX),gcc)   # for some reason CXX is gcc on cygwin 1.1.4
CXX = g++49
endif
```

So I'd like the almighty of someone here to instruct it to compile with gcc49 (or g++49?) instead. Thanks!

Makefile:

```
CXXFLAGS = -DNDEBUG -g -O2
#CXXFLAGS = -g
# -fPIC is supported. Please report any breakage of -fPIC as a bug.
# CXXFLAGS += -fPIC
# the following options reduce code size, but breaks link or makes link very slow on some systems
# CXXFLAGS += -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections
# LDFLAGS += -Wl,--gc-sections

ARFLAGS = -cr   # ar needs the dash on OpenBSD
RANLIB = ranlib
CP = cp
MKDIR = mkdir
EGREP = egrep
UNAME = $(shell uname)
ISX86 = $(shell uname -m | $(EGREP) -c "i.86|x86|i86|amd64")

# Default prefix for make install
ifeq ($(PREFIX),)
PREFIX = ..
endif

ifeq ($(CXX),gcc)   # for some reason CXX is gcc on cygwin 1.1.4
CXX = g++49
endif

ifeq ($(ISX86),1)

GCC42_OR_LATER = $(shell $(CXX) -v 2>&1 | $(EGREP) -c "^gcc version (4.[2-9]|[5-9])")
INTEL_COMPILER = $(shell $(CXX) --version 2>&1 | $(EGREP) -c "\(ICC\)")
ICC111_OR_LATER = $(shell $(CXX) --version 2>&1 | $(EGREP) -c "\(ICC\) ([2-9][0-9]|1[2-9]|11\.[1-9])")
IS_SUN_CC = $(shell $(CXX) -V 2>&1 | $(EGREP) -c "CC: Sun")
GAS210_OR_LATER = $(shell echo "" | $(AS) -v 2>&1 | $(EGREP) -c "GNU assembler version (2\.[1-9][0-9]|[3-9])")
GAS217_OR_LATER = $(shell echo "" | $(AS) -v 2>&1 | $(EGREP) -c "GNU assembler version (2\.1[7-9]|2\.[2-9]|[3-9])")
GAS219_OR_LATER = $(shell echo "" | $(AS) -v 2>&1 | $(EGREP) -c "GNU assembler version (2\.19|2\.[2-9]|[3-9])")
ISMINGW = $(shell $(CXX) --version 2>&1 | $(EGREP) -c "mingw")

ifneq ($(GCC42_OR_LATER),0)
ifeq ($(UNAME),Darwin)
CXXFLAGS += -arch x86_64 -arch i386
else
CXXFLAGS += -march=native
endif
endif

ifneq ($(INTEL_COMPILER),0)
CXXFLAGS += -wd68 -wd186 -wd279 -wd327
ifeq ($(ICC111_OR_LATER),0)
# "internal error: backend signals" occurs on some x86 inline assembly with ICC 9 and some x64 inline assembly with ICC 11.0
# if you want to use Crypto++'s assembly code with ICC, try enabling it on individual files
CXXFLAGS += -DCRYPTOPP_DISABLE_ASM
endif
endif

ifeq ($(GAS210_OR_LATER),0) # .intel_syntax wasn't supported until GNU assembler 2.10
CXXFLAGS += -DCRYPTOPP_DISABLE_ASM
else
ifeq ($(GAS217_OR_LATER),0)
CXXFLAGS += -DCRYPTOPP_DISABLE_SSSE3
else
ifeq ($(GAS219_OR_LATER),0)
CXXFLAGS += -DCRYPTOPP_DISABLE_AESNI
endif
endif
ifeq ($(UNAME),SunOS)
CXXFLAGS += -Wa,--divide    # allow use of "/" operator
endif
endif

ifeq ($(ISMINGW),1)
LDLIBS += -lws2_32
endif

endif   # ISX86

ifeq ($(UNAME),)    # for DJGPP, where uname doesn't exist
CXXFLAGS += -mbnu210
else
CXXFLAGS += -pipe
endif

ifeq ($(UNAME),Linux)
LDFLAGS += -pthread
ifneq ($(shell uname -i | $(EGREP) -c "(_64|d64)"),0)
M32OR64 = -m64
endif
endif

ifeq ($(UNAME),Darwin)
AR = libtool
ARFLAGS = -static -o
CXX = c++
IS_GCC2 = $(shell $(CXX) -v 2>&1 | $(EGREP) -c gcc-932)
ifeq ($(IS_GCC2),1)
CXXFLAGS += -fno-coalesce-templates -fno-coalesce-static-vtables
LDLIBS += -lstdc++
LDFLAGS += -flat_namespace -undefined suppress -m
endif
endif

ifeq ($(UNAME),SunOS)
LDLIBS += -lnsl -lsocket
M32OR64 = -m$(shell isainfo -b)
endif

ifneq ($(IS_SUN_CC),0)  # override flags for CC Sun C++ compiler
CXXFLAGS = -DNDEBUG -O -g0 -native -template=no%extdef $(M32OR64)
LDFLAGS =
AR = $(CXX)
ARFLAGS = -xar -o
RANLIB = true
SUN_CC10_BUGGY = $(shell $(CXX) -V 2>&1 | $(EGREP) -c "CC: Sun .* 5\.10 .* (2009|2010/0[1-4])")
ifneq ($(SUN_CC10_BUGGY),0)
# -DCRYPTOPP_INCLUDE_VECTOR_CC is needed for Sun Studio 12u1 Sun C++ 5.10 SunOS_i386 128229-02 2009/09/21 and was fixed in May 2010
# remove it if you get "already had a body defined" errors in vector.cc
CXXFLAGS += -DCRYPTOPP_INCLUDE_VECTOR_CC
endif
endif

SRCS = $(wildcard *.cpp)
ifeq ($(SRCS),)             # workaround wildcard function bug in GNU Make 3.77
SRCS = $(shell echo *.cpp)
endif

OBJS = $(SRCS:.cpp=.o)
# test.o needs to be after bench.o for cygwin 1.1.4 (possible ld bug?)
TESTOBJS = bench.o bench2.o test.o validat1.o validat2.o validat3.o adhoc.o datatest.o regtest.o fipsalgt.o dlltest.o
LIBOBJS = $(filter-out $(TESTOBJS),$(OBJS))

DLLSRCS = algebra.cpp algparam.cpp asn.cpp basecode.cpp cbcmac.cpp channels.cpp cryptlib.cpp des.cpp dessp.cpp dh.cpp dll.cpp dsa.cpp ec2n.cpp eccrypto.cpp ecp.cpp eprecomp.cpp files.cpp filters.cpp fips140.cpp fipstest.cpp gf2n.cpp gfpcrypt.cpp hex.cpp hmac.cpp integer.cpp iterhash.cpp misc.cpp modes.cpp modexppc.cpp mqueue.cpp nbtheory.cpp oaep.cpp osrng.cpp pch.cpp pkcspad.cpp pubkey.cpp queue.cpp randpool.cpp rdtables.cpp rijndael.cpp rng.cpp rsa.cpp sha.cpp simple.cpp skipjack.cpp strciphr.cpp trdlocal.cpp
DLLOBJS = $(DLLSRCS:.cpp=.export.o)
LIBIMPORTOBJS = $(LIBOBJS:.o=.import.o)
TESTIMPORTOBJS = $(TESTOBJS:.o=.import.o)
DLLTESTOBJS = dlltest.dllonly.o

all: cryptest.exe

test: cryptest.exe
    ./cryptest.exe v

clean:
    $(RM) cryptest.exe libcryptopp.a $(LIBOBJS) $(TESTOBJS) cryptopp.dll libcryptopp.dll.a libcryptopp.import.a cryptest.import.exe dlltest.exe $(DLLOBJS) $(LIBIMPORTOBJS) $(TESTIMPORTOBJS) $(DLLTESTOBJS)

install:
    $(MKDIR) -p $(PREFIX)/include/cryptopp $(PREFIX)/lib $(PREFIX)/bin
    $(CP) *.h $(PREFIX)/include/cryptopp
    $(CP) *.a $(PREFIX)/lib
    $(CP) *.so $(PREFIX)/lib
    $(CP) *.exe $(PREFIX)/bin

libcryptopp.a: $(LIBOBJS)
    $(AR) $(ARFLAGS) $@ $(LIBOBJS)
    $(RANLIB) $@

libcryptopp.so: $(LIBOBJS)
    $(CXX) -shared -o $@ $(LIBOBJS)

cryptest.exe: libcryptopp.a $(TESTOBJS)
    $(CXX) -o $@ $(CXXFLAGS) $(TESTOBJS) -L. -lcryptopp $(LDFLAGS) $(LDLIBS)

nolib: $(OBJS)      # makes it faster to test changes
    $(CXX) -o ct $(CXXFLAGS) $(OBJS) $(LDFLAGS) $(LDLIBS)

dll: cryptest.import.exe dlltest.exe

cryptopp.dll: $(DLLOBJS)
    $(CXX) -shared -o $@ $(CXXFLAGS) $(DLLOBJS) $(LDFLAGS) $(LDLIBS) -Wl,--out-implib=libcryptopp.dll.a

libcryptopp.import.a: $(LIBIMPORTOBJS)
    $(AR) $(ARFLAGS) $@ $(LIBIMPORTOBJS)
    $(RANLIB) $@

cryptest.import.exe: cryptopp.dll libcryptopp.import.a $(TESTIMPORTOBJS)
    $(CXX) -o $@ $(CXXFLAGS) $(TESTIMPORTOBJS) -L. -lcryptopp.dll -lcryptopp.import $(LDFLAGS) $(LDLIBS)

dlltest.exe: cryptopp.dll $(DLLTESTOBJS)
    $(CXX) -o $@ $(CXXFLAGS) $(DLLTESTOBJS) -L. -lcryptopp.dll $(LDFLAGS) $(LDLIBS)

adhoc.cpp: adhoc.cpp.proto
ifeq ($(wildcard adhoc.cpp),)
    cp adhoc.cpp.proto adhoc.cpp
else
    touch adhoc.cpp
endif

%.dllonly.o : %.cpp
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -DCRYPTOPP_DLL_ONLY -c $< -o $@

%.import.o : %.cpp
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -DCRYPTOPP_IMPORTS -c $< -o $@

%.export.o : %.cpp
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -DCRYPTOPP_EXPORTS -c $< -o $@

%.o : %.cpp
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -c $<
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> ifeq ($(CXX),gcc)   # for some reason CXX is gcc on cygwin 1.1.4
> CXX = g++49
> endif
> ```

If I recall correctly, `CXX` is `g++` or `c++` on the BSDs, so you will never enter the `ifeq` block.

The easiest thing to do would probably be:

```
# GNUmakefile
CXXFLAGS = -DNDEBUG -g -O2 -fPIC
CXX=g++49
...
```

---

It looks like you are using Crypto++ 5.6.2 or less because of this line:

```
CXXFLAGS = -DNDEBUG -g -O2
```

5.6.3 and above works harder at honoring user's preferences. For example, in [5.6.3 GNUmakefile](https://github.com/weidai11/cryptopp/blob/master/GNUmakefile) (which is being tested for release):

```
# Base CXXFLAGS used if the user did not specify them
CXXFLAGS ?= -DNDEBUG -g2 -O2
```

The next-easiest thing to do would be to grab the [5.6.3 GNUmakefile](https://github.com/weidai11/cryptopp/blob/master/GNUmakefile), and then peform the following (`g++49` must be on-path):

```
export CXX=g++49
make
```

I can assure you that works on 5.6.3 because I made the changes to facilitate testing under different compilers. You can also tweak `CXXFLAGS`:

```
export CXX=/opt/intel/bin/icpc
export CXXFLAGS="-DNDEBUG -g2 -O3 -wd68 -wd186"
make
```

---

5.6.3 should be available in a couple of weeks. We are finishing up the mitigations for a [Coverity scan/analysis](https://scan.coverity.com/projects/cryptopp). Once they are mitigated, we have to perform a final round or [Release Testing](https://cryptopp.com/wiki/Release_Testing).

Comment: Wow I've just tried it and it works perfectly! Thank you man! I regret not having enough points so I could up vote your great on-point answer!